# What is the most powerful processor you can use for an Alienware 17 R3 laptop?

Tags: processor

If you can't name just one, name a few. In this case, price does not matter. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like this laptop model uses soldered-on CPUs, ie "just pick the CPU with the highest number and a K behind the number".

Comment: So this https://www.amazon.com/Intel-BX80684I78700K-Core-i7-8700K-Processor/dp/B07598VZR8/ref=sr_1_23?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1511113573&sr=1-23&keywords=processor is better than this? https://www.amazon.com/Intel-i7-6850K-Processor-FC-LGA14A-BX80671I76850K/dp/B01FJLAITC/ref=sr_1_11?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1511113573&sr=1-11&keywords=processor

Comment: Yes, the 8700K should do better than the 6850K. However AFAICT neither is compatible with the Alienware 17 R4.

Comment: How can you tell if it's compatible?

Comment: The [17R4](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N0THPHM/) runs on an [Intel Core i7-7820HK](https://ark.intel.com/products/97464) which uses the `FCBGA1440` socket. This means that a) the pin-counts miss-match with the other CPUs (1440 vs 1151 vs 2011) and b) that the CPU is _physically soldered onto the board and not removable_. Thus an upgrade of the CPU is not possible.

Comment: Crap sorry I meant r3. I have the Intel i7-6700hq.

Comment: It's the same story with the 6700HQ as with the 7820HK.

Comment: How do you finish a forum post? Do you just leave it?

Comment: Okay. Please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alienware 17 R3 and R4 run on Intel Core i7-6700HQ or i7-7820HK.

These [CPUs](https://ark.intel.com/products/97464) run the socket `FCBGA1440`. Thus it cannot be upgraded, especially not with a desktop-grade CPU.

- The Pin-count (1440) miss-matches those of the desktop CPUs (1151, 2011).
- The CPU is physically soldered onto the board, it cannot be easily removed and even if you would succeed, you'd be back to the first point and these CPUs are just about the most beefy CPUs there are for this socket / power class.